# Playframework Closure Compiler concatenates javascript in the wrong order

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, google-closure-compiler, playframework-2.2

I have a couple of legacy Javascript files that sits in app/assets/javascripts

When running play run I only include the generated file: 'main.min.js' and there I can see all the assets concatenated and minified.

I have some dependencies between elements in the different Javascript files thus they must be concatenated in a certain way.

I tried giving them prefixes 0_file.js .. 99_file.js and made sure that when using Google copmiler.jar --js 0_file.js .. --js 99_file.js it does keep the order.

I then moved to the [Play documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/AssetsGoogleClosureCompiler) where I found the default behavior:

```
javascriptEntryPoints <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile)(base =>
   ((base / "assets" ** "*.js") --- (base / "assets" ** "_*")).get
)
```

I'm no Scala expert, but I hope this default fetching of files doesn't get them ordered like I want - so the problem can be solved by fixing this source fetching to keep them ordered.

How can I change the code here to fetch files alphabetically.

Or - How can I control the order of files before sending them to Closure Compiler.

EDIT

I just realized Build.scala was dropped in the Play version I'm using (2.2.1) so I'd also like to know where I should add the javascriptEntryPoints Seq and how it related to 
play.Project.playScalaSettings in build.sbt file.

Answer (score 2):

One way we could order the list of files returned from the PathFinder is just sort them. Something like this

```
 val sortFiles:Seq[File] => Seq[File]  = files => files.sortWith(_.getName < _.getName)

 javascriptEntryPoints <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile)(base =>
      sortFiles(((base / "assets" ** "*.js") --- (base / "assets" ** "_*")).get)
 )
```

Here the sortFiles take seq of files and sort them using sortWith method. The sortWith method invokes the passed in function with two files. In this example I am using getName and sorting them using string comparison.

Comment: thanks, please see edit - I don't know where to add these since I don't have Build.scala in Play 2.1.1

Comment: @ChenHarel just put this into your build.sbt file. W/o the sortFiles function you could do it in one line: 
```javascriptEntryPoints <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile)(base => 
      ((base / "assets" ** "*.js") --- (base / "assets" ** "_*")).get.sortBy(_.getName)
)```

Comment: sadly that didn't help.. i tried putting it before and after play.Project.playScalaSettings. is there any way to add debug information to the google compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the bottom of your Build.scala to test

```
val base = new File("./app/")
val list = ((base / "assets" ** "*.js") --- (base / "assets" ** "_*")).get.sortBy(_.name)
list.foreach(println)
```

In the sbt console run `reload` to trigger the code, tweak the base and sortBy to your needs, or use any other collection methods to manipulate the result. You could also log this during the build by adding `.map{ f => println(f);f}`

for me this prints the following, even without the sort...

```
./app/assets/javascripts/jquery.smartbanner.js
./app/assets/javascripts/main.js
./app/assets/javascripts/search.js
./app/assets/javascripts/searchBox.js
```

Comment: thanks, please see edit - I don't know where to add these since I don't have Build.scala in Play 2.1.1

Comment: just add the .map{ f => println(f);f} after the sort to debug and check the logs during build